# ruby on rails. has many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a genre and movie models they are associated with has many through. when calling from browser i'm receiving error about categorization which is join model.
Error:  undefined local variable or method `categorizations' for Class:0x00000007be0120>

This is the controller...

```
class GenreController < ApplicationController

   def updateList
     result=Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('url'))
     json = JSON.parse(result)

     json['genres'].each do |data|
       obj = Genre.new(
            tmdb_id: data['id'],
            name: data['name']
            )
     end

   end

end
```

this is model

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :movies, :through => categorizations

end
```

i know that there should be validations for this but right now i'm just populating genre table. There should be a create but i'm just trying to see the result.

**EDIT**:

Model for categorization

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :genre
end
```

Model for Movies

```
  class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :roles
      has_many :actors, :through => :roles

      has_many :watchlists
      has_many :users, :through => :watchlists

      has_many :categorizations
      has_many :genres, :through => :categorizations

      has_many :videos

  end
```

Comment: Can you post your categorization and movie model?

Comment: Where exactly you get that error? Please post the full error stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
has_many :movies, :through => categorizations
```

You need to have a colon before "categorizations":

```
has_many :movies, :through => :categorizations
```

Comment: Could you suggest a better way to code to avoid such mistakes. IDE?

Comment: I suppose "experience" is the best answer.  I don't know if an IDE would help as your code is valid Ruby code, just not what you wanted.

Comment: @Geek101 Syntax highlighting helps considerably, but developing an eye for these things comes naturally over time.